# Web app with real-time messaging hangs when too many messages are being sent

Tags: nginx, websocket, real-time, django-channels

I am practicing a group chat app using django channels and nginx. The problem is if I do a stress test like 300 users will send messages between 2-4 seconds within 2 minutes. The tab that has our web app will hang. How can I prevent this? Will nginx's gzip help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my understanding you send around 100 messages per sec during 2 mins.

The main 2 things here that can lead to CPU overload are:

- Very intense network traffic
- Heavy JavaScript code that renders all these messages

So you need to check both of them

For example, you can start by checking JavaScript part. Try to disable a code that shows all incoming messages in UI, so only network part will be active. See how it works. If it works good now, then you need to optimize this JavaScript part, maybe collect incoming messages in memory and show messages in UI each 3 seconds instead of each 100/1 seconds. This will save your rendering power.

Regarding network part - you can try to optimize a message payload - make it smaller.

Comment: Are you saying that I should only limit the messages seen by default by let's say 25? So if there is a single new message then I will hide the oldest one displayed?

Comment: Now, I mean you should minimize the frequency of changes in UI. Because render 100 messages in UI per q sec is too frequent

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada you are welcome, let me know about results or you need additional help

Comment: You are right, so we just minimized the messages  to 25 per second.